# What's the pronoun for two uncountable nouns?

Tags: pronouns, uncountable-nouns

Which is correct?

- I bought some beef and pork. All of **it looks** fresh.
- I bought some beef and pork. All of **them look** fresh.

Since both "beef" and "pork" are uncountable nouns, I think the we should use the pronoun "it" to replace "beef and pork."

However, when it comes to the following sentence, I think we should consider them as plural to make the subject agree with the verb. And that makes me confused.

- Beef and pork **are** expensive.

Answer (score 2):

you are comparing apples and oranges

with

> I bought some beef and pork. All of it looks fresh

I think... You have turned beef and pork into a single item you bought some meat, a single item

but with

> Beef and pork are expensive.

you are creating a list of items that are expensive.

Comment: So do you mean "All of them look fresh" is not a good sentence? Is this sentence possible? Thank you Wendy. Your explanation helps me a lot.

Comment: you are correct in your original analysis, yes "all of them" is the wrong construct